# How to make POSIX/Linux signal handling safe?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I've just implemented asynchronous file reading using GNU Asynchronous I/O and signals. I handle result using signals with callback handler (SIGUSR1 target):

```
static
void aioSigHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext)
{
    struct aioRequest *request = si->si_value.sival_ptr;
    int bytes_read = aio_return(request->aiocbp);

    printf("I/O completion signal received %d: %.*s\n", bytes_read, bytes_read, request->aiocbp->aio_buf);

    // continue reading if whole buffer was filled
    if(bytes_read == BUF_SIZE) {
        request->aiocbp->aio_offset += bytes_read;

        if (aio_read(request->aiocbp) == -1)
            errExit("aio_read");
    } else {
        request->finished = 1;
    }
}
```

I wonder what could happen if someone sends SIGUSR1 to my process. Obviosly it won't have `siginfo_t *si` populated with instance of my structure, therefore I read garbage, and in lucky situation the program would immediately end with segfault. In bad scenario some other data get corrupted and the error wouldn't be detected. How can I protect against that?

Complete source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4          /* Size of buffers for read operations */
#define IO_SIGNAL SIGUSR1   /* Signal used to notify I/O completion */

#define errExit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
#define errMsg(msg)  do { perror(msg); } while (0)

static volatile sig_atomic_t gotSIGQUIT = 0;

struct aioRequest {
    int           finished;
    struct aiocb *aiocbp;
};

static void                 aioSigHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext);
static const char *         aioStatusToString(int status);
static struct aioRequest *  aioReadingStart(const char *filename);
static void                 quitHandler(int sig);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    sa.sa_handler = quitHandler;
    if (sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigaction");

    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = aioSigHandler;
    if (sigaction(IO_SIGNAL, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigaction");

    struct aioRequest *request = aioReadingStart(argv[1]);

    while (1) {
        sleep(3);       /* Delay between each monitoring step */

        if(request->finished) {
            break;
        }

        int status = aio_error(request->aiocbp);
        if (status != EINPROGRESS) {
            printf("aio_error() for request (descriptor %d): ", request->aiocbp->aio_fildes);
            printf("%s\n",aioStatusToString(status));
            break;
        }

        if (gotSIGQUIT) {
            /* On receipt of SIGQUIT, attempt to cancel I/O requests,
             * and display status returned
             * from the cancellation request */
            printf("got SIGQUIT; canceling I/O request: ");

            int s = aio_cancel(request->aiocbp->aio_fildes, request->aiocbp);
            if (s == AIO_CANCELED)
                printf("I/O canceled\n");
            else if (s == AIO_NOTCANCELED)
                printf("I/O not canceled\n");
            else if (s == AIO_ALLDONE)
                printf("I/O all done\n");
            else
                errMsg("aio_cancel");

            gotSIGQUIT = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("File reading completed\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static
void aioSigHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext)
{
    struct aioRequest *request = si->si_value.sival_ptr;
    int bytes_read = aio_return(request->aiocbp);

    printf("I/O completion signal received %d: %.*s\n", bytes_read, bytes_read, request->aiocbp->aio_buf);

    // continue reading if whole buffer was filled
    if(bytes_read == BUF_SIZE) {
        request->aiocbp->aio_offset += bytes_read;

        if (aio_read(request->aiocbp) == -1)
            errExit("aio_read");
    } else {
        request->finished = 1;
    }
}

static
const char * aioStatusToString(int status) {
    switch (status) {
        case 0:
            return "I/O succeeded\n";
        case EINPROGRESS:
            return "In progress\n";
        case ECANCELED:
            return "Canceled\n";
        default:
            errMsg("aio_error");
            return 0;
    }
}

static
struct aioRequest * aioReadingStart(const char *filename) {
    struct aioRequest *request = malloc(sizeof(struct aioRequest));
    struct aiocb *aiocbInstance = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));

    if (request == NULL || aiocbInstance == NULL)
        errExit("malloc");

    request->finished = 0;
    request->aiocbp = aiocbInstance;

    request->aiocbp->aio_fildes = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (request->aiocbp->aio_fildes == -1)
        errExit("open");
    printf("opened %s on descriptor %d\n", filename,
           request->aiocbp->aio_fildes);

    request->aiocbp->aio_buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    if (request->aiocbp->aio_buf == NULL)
        errExit("malloc");

    request->aiocbp->aio_nbytes = BUF_SIZE;
    request->aiocbp->aio_reqprio = 0;
    request->aiocbp->aio_offset = 0;
    request->aiocbp->aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    request->aiocbp->aio_sigevent.sigev_signo = IO_SIGNAL;
    request->aiocbp->aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = request;

    if (aio_read(request->aiocbp) == -1)
        errExit("aio_read");

    return request;
}

static void
quitHandler(int sig) {
    gotSIGQUIT = 1;
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Well, sorry. I've probably missclicked and overlooked it, because I was more focused on the topic. But, why down-vote and close request? I know the difference between C and C++, they are very different language with some subset of similar features, but they have different ABI.

Comment: How to make it signal-safe?  Don't call non-async-signal-safe functions like `printf()` and `aio_read()` in a signal handler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, that's one point, not exactly what I was asking. Thanks for the warning. In real code I'm gonna put the result to the queue, and it gets processed later.

Comment: Temporal coincidence does not imply causality.

Comment: @Olaf I'm glad you didn't do it, but quite angry at people, who just down-vote hard questions without explanation. I see it as quite legitimate question of a man, who goes much deeper with his knowledge than most of the "programmers" will ever touch in their entire life.

Comment: Don't really understand your problem. Why don't test for SIGUSR1 in the handler? Or just don't use `SA_INFO` for SIGUSR1 handling and set to another handling function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To focus on the stated question, I shall limit my suggestions to the signal handling aspect.

Consider using a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0`, inclusive) instead of `SIGUSR1`. Standard signals such as `SIGUSR1` are not queued, so you may lose them (if you have one already pending when another same signal triggers), but realtime signals are queued, and much more reliable. See Real-time signals section in [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for details.

Also consider saving `errno` at the beginning of your signal handler, and restoring it before returning. Otherwise, it is possible that in some corner cases the signal delivery "corrupts" `errno` (because your signal handler modifies it implicitly), which is very hard to debug -- simply put, in some cases the `errno` you think was assigned due to a failed syscall, was actually reset by your signal handler.

(Language-lawyers might point out that accessing thread-local variables, `errno` typically being one, is non-async-signal safe, at least in theory. In practice it is safe, especially if the thread-local variables have been accessed by the thread prior to the signal. For further details regarding glibc, see [this thread](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2013-09/msg00563.html) at the libc-alpha mailing list. Personally, I create my pthreads with smaller than default stacks (the default being way too large for typical worker threads), and ensure the thread function reads and writes thread-local variables as the first thing, avoiding any thread-local non-async-signal-safe issues in practice. This also applies to the main thread. In short, if the thread-local variables are known to be allocated and available prior to the signal delivery, their use is, *in practice*, async-signal-safe. Finally, async-signal-safe functions such as `read()` and `write()` do modify `errno` [internally](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=io/read.c;hb=HEAD), without [any special handling](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=include/errno.h;hb=HEAD), so if they are async-signal-safe, restoring `errno` has to be too.)

As described in the [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page, and mentioned by Andrew Henle in a comment to the original question, only async-signal-safe functions are safe to use in a signal handler. Neither `aio_read()` nor `printf()` are async-signal-safe.

Note that [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) are async-signal-safe, and can be used with eg. an anonymous socket pair to transfer an information package (describing the event) to an event-processing thread, or to print (debugging) information to standard output or standard error (`STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` descriptors, respectively).

If you absolutely need to use non-async-signal-safe functions, block those signals, and create a helper thread that uses [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) to handle the signals. This won't necessarily work for thread-targeted signals on Linux, and I personally would use a signal handler, GCC atomic builtins (they're supported by most C compilers, fortunately) to maintain a queue of events, and e.g. [`sem_post()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html) to wake up the event-processing thread. There are several design options here, and thus far even the oddball problems I've come across have always been solvable using a relatively straightforward approach.

As described in the [`man 2 sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) man page, you can examine `si->code` to find out the reason for the signal; it will be `SI_ASYNCIO` for AIO completions, `POLL_IN`/`POLL_OUT`/`POLL_MSG`/`POLL_ERR`/`POLL_PRI`/`POLL_HUP` for SIGIO signals, `SI_KERNEL` for other kernel-sent signals, and so on. If `si->code` is `SI_USER` or `SI_QUEUE`, you can examine `si->pid` to find out which process sent the signal.

It is also recommended to clear the entire `struct sigaction` via e.g. `memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);` prior to setting any of the fields. (This is because some of the fields may or may not be unions; clearing the entire structure to all zeros ensures "safe" values for the unused fields.)

Hmm, did I forget something? If you notice something I missed, please let me know in the comments, so I can fix this answer.

Comment: Thanks. So, In short: use only async-signal-safe functions; and to asure that `si->si_value.sival_ptr` is instance of my struct `struct aioRequest`, I must check the `si->si_code` and `si->si_pid`. Am I right? So, there is no other way to have guarantee that `si->si_value.sival_ptr` is instance of my struct `struct aioRequest`?

Comment: It is sufficient to check if `si->si_pid == getpid() && si->si_code == SI_ASYNCIO`. If true, then the signal was raised due to AIO completion, and you should have a pointer to your struct in `si->si_value.sival_ptr` (as set when creating the AIO request). I see no reason for additional checks. In addition to async-signal-safe functions, consider using a realtime signal (I recommend `SIGRTMIN+0`) instead of `SIGUSR1`, and saving and restoring `errno` in the signal handler.

Comment: Well. Thank you for the answer, and other useful info that I wasn't expecting to get. I see, that I've got to learn a lot of about signals.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for the answer. Do you have any knowledge of whether the access-thread-locals-at-the-start-of-a-thread approach should guarantee AS-safety on non-Linux platforms as well (I'm mainly interested in Cygwin and MacOS)?